# How do I use sed to substitute the third occurrence of the same regex in the file?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a problem finding a `sed` script that works when the regex looks exactly the same but I only want to substitute one.

The file looks like this:

```
something someting something
this 
something someting something
something someting something
this 
someting something
someting something
someting something
this
someting something
someting something
this
```

I want to substitute the third "this" to something else. I have tried with:

```
sed '3,/this.*/s/this.*/something/'
```

and various similar attempts, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't easy in sed but awk can do it

```
awk '/this/{count++;if(count==3){sub("this","something")}}1'
```

Comment: Simple and that's why I love `awk` more than `sed`. Though I don't know much `sed` anyways. :) +1

Comment: @lain You are really active for a guy who is 91. Too bad I can't give more +1s. ;)

Comment: @lain How do i print that to a file? My Awk fu is not that good. My command looks like this: 

    echo | sh -c "awk '/this/{count++;if(count==3){sub(\"this\",\"something\")}}1' >> /to/file"

Comment: @AlMehdi If you have your content in a file then just do `awk '/this/{count++;if(count==3){sub("this","something")}}1' your_file > new_file` and you should be good.

Comment: I need it to be the same file. It is a theme file bult in css. I want to change an alignment from right to left. In `Sed` i just add an `-i` but for awk i do not know. It don't seam like i can append.. not sure if that is possible either. I am guissing i need to `{print}` in some way.. but don't know how.

Comment: mv theme.file theme.file.tmp; awk '...' theme.file.tmp >theme.file

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't actually go so far as to say it is impossible in `sed`; I would definitely say it is not the appropriate tool for this job.  I'd drop into Perl, but pick your scripting language of choice.

#### Untested!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $this_count = 0;
LINE:
while (<>)
{
    if (m/^this$/ && ++$this_count == 3)
    {
        $_ = "that\n";  # Note the newline; I didn't chomp!
    }
    print;
}
```

Comment: More concisely written as `perl -pe 's/^this/that/ if /^this/ && ++$c == 3' input_file` (and this one is tested :-))

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
# do nothing the first 2 times (weird sed counting makes that 3)
3,/this.*/n
# then, substitute only once
1,/this.*/ s/this.*/foo/
```

To embed the newline in a shell script, I'd probably cheat using the GNU "echo -e" to embed a "\n":

```
sed -e "$(echo -e "3,/this.*/n\n1,/this.*/ s/this.*/foo/ ")"
```

Comment: A better way to inline a newline is to say `$'\n'`, if your shell supports it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/this/{x;s/^/X/;/^XXX$/!{x;b};x;s/this/something/}' file
```

Explanation:

For each occurrence of `this` append an `X` to the hold space (HS). When the HS contains 3 `X`'s replace `this` with `something`.

EDIT:

This will also work too (basic same idea):

```
sed -e '/this/{x;s/^/X/;/^XXX$/!{x;b};x;c\something' -e '}' file
```